# How to add custom menu item to an existing app?

Tags: c#

C#.

Example: [image]
<sub>(source: [brianapps.net](http://www.brianapps.net/sysmenuint.png))</sub>

I'm working on a screen capture software, so I want to enable specific window capture.

Comment: You'll need to give us more information on the application you're trying to extend - like which one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  mnuHandle = GetSystemMenu(hwnd, false)

  //add a line to the end
  AppendMenu(mnuHandle, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, "")

  //2 add a command ID = 200
  AppendMenu(mnuHandle, MF_STRING, 0x200, "Command &1")
  AppendMenu(mnuHandle, MF_STRING, 0x201, "Command &2")

  //insert a new item to the 2. position
  InsertMenu(mnuHandle, 2, MF_BYPOSITION, 0x202, "Command &3")

  //remove a standard item 
  RemoveMenu(mnuHandle, 0, MF_BYPOSITION)
```

it's not the point to create the menu items in the system menu of a totally different application... the question is more or less how would you hook the upcoming system menu events?

If resizing an arbitrary window is what you want to do: just fetch the window handle of the program (how would you do this?) and call SetWindowPos http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can call the [`GetSystemMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647985%28VS.85%29.aspx) API method to get a handle to an existing window's system menu.

You can then call [`InsertMenuItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647988%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to add an item to the menu.